# Functions | are the sentence and the proof are correct

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification

Let $c,L,M$ be real numbers, and let $f,g,h$ be real valued functions.
suppose the next conditions:

- $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$
- $g$ is continuous at L.
- $\forall x[h(x)=g(f(x))]$
  then we have:
  $$\lim_{x \to c} h(x) = g(L)$$
  $Proof.$ Let $U$ be a punctured neighborhood of $g(L)$. By the second condition, there is a punctured neighborhood $V^*$ of $L$ such that:
  $$\forall x\in V^*[g(x)\in U] (1)$$
  By the first condition, there is a punctured neighborhood $V$ of c such that:
  $$\forall x\in V[f(x)\in V^*](2)$$

Now let $x \in V$. According to (2) - $f(x)\in V^*$. Therefore, according to (1) and the third condition, we get: $h(x)\in U$.

---

Are the theorem and the proof correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I can deduce that the codomains of f,g, and h are probably the reals, but you could maybe say what their domains are also. It is always inconvenient to have to have to stop reading in order to deduce myself what the domains and codomains are when the author does not include them. Also what is an "environment" here, do you perhaps mean a neighborhood?. Also, if L is a real number then how is g continuous in L? In general, just please be more specific, for all I know this could be a complex analysis question (even though I suspect it is real analysis, since c, L, and M are real).

Comment: Yes, I meant neighborhood.

Comment: Ok, but please clarify those other things I mentioned. I recommend that you edit your question, if your question is easier to read, then you will likely get an answer more quickly.

Comment: @Countable can you elaborate on what to clarify?